# Export data from a database in Server management studio to Zoho using the Zoho Python SDK and Pyodbc

Tags: python, zoho, zcrmsdk

I'm currently writing a Python script to export data to Zoho from Server Management Studio (SSMS) using python.
But it seems like A lot of information provided is not up to date and not usable anymore because the Zoho Python SDK has changed a lot.

This is what I have now:

```
# Use pyodbc to connect to the SQL Server database where you have data stored.
import pyodbc

server = r'MSSQLZOHO'
database = 'ZOHO'
username = '_____'
password = '_____'

connection_string = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password};Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

# Write an SQL query to select the data you want to import.
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Debiteurs'
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

This part works but now I want to use the Zoho python SDK module to make a connection with the Zoho API to import data,
but I don't find the information provided in the Zoho documentation and on https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-python-sdk and so clear. Does anyone have some advice? Much appreciated.